# Trouble adding policy to s3 bucket in serverless.yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have the following policy I would like to add to my S3 bucket

```
s3Permissions:
  Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
  Properties:
    Bucket: ${self:provider.environment.S3_BUCKET}
    PolicyDocument:
        Id: Policy1590589947784
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Sid: getObjectFromS3
          Action:
          - s3:GetObject
          Effect: Allow
          Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.S3_BUCKET}
          Principal: "*"
```

I have this setup as one of my environment variables

```
S3_BUCKET: com.backbar.lookups.${self:provider.stage}
```

I get the following error when I try to deploy

```
An error occurred: s3Permissions - Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicy; Request ID: 3760256F6D1080A1; S3 Extended Request ID: ...
```

How do I correctly set the bucket policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that instead of:

```
Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.S3_BUCKET}
```

it should be:

```
Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:provider.environment.S3_BUCKET}/*
```

`s3:GetObject` applies to objects. Your original `Resource` is a bucket.